# Saving html numbers in array then print them all

Tags: arrays, session, numbers, save

So I need to create a page in which a person can add numbers. When the person presses the button next, you can fill out another number. When you eventually press the button done, it sorts all the numbers from highest to lowest.

Now the thing I'm not getting is, should I create an array and then print them from highest > lowest or should I let it create a session. I literally have no clue how to do this and I can't find any help through Google. This is what I came up with so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Getallen invullen
    </title>
</head>
<body>


    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['getallen'] = 0;

    ?>


    Vul hieronder getallen in:<br>
    <form action="verwerken2.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="getallen" value="0">
        <input type="number" name="input" value="input">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Volgende"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="done" value="Klaar">
    </form>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: Well, technically this can all be accomplished client-side in JavaScript without any need for PHP. Just store the numbers in an array and, when done, sort the array and display it. In PHP the concept is still the same, the array just needs to persist across requests (such as in session state). Each time a number is posted, add it to the array stored in the session. When done, take the array from session, sort it, and display it. Of the handful of discrete pieces of functionality here (posting a value, creating an array, using session, sorting an array, etc.) where are you stuck?

Comment: The thing I'm stuck with is, how exactly do I make it so the numbers that I fill in are sorted in an array?

Comment: If you're doing this in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php  If you're doing this in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort  Sorting an array is a very common thing in any programming language, a cursory Google search can find more information about it.